# Tablelayout: Text in the last column is not getting displayed completly

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, android-tablelayout

Please have a look at the following code

```
<TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/sales_inq_table"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="2"
            android:shrinkColumns="1" 
             >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/presence_audio_online" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/testWord"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="John"
                     />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="0094 111 1111 111" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/presence_audio_away" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Burrows" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:text="0094 111 1111 111" />
            </TableRow>


        </TableLayout>
```

In this code, in the second column, there is a 14 digits number. Only part of this text is getting displayed. I have tried lot of ways to solve this, but the issue still remains as it is. Following image shows this.

If I remove `strechColumns` and add custom padding/margin, what will happen is that if the name is short, then the particular number will get displayed bit more aligned to left than the second field number. Not like that, all the numbers in all fields should be align properly, vertically.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/sales_inq_table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="0"
    android:stretchColumns="1" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@android:drawable/presence_audio_online" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/testWord"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="John"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="0094 111 1111 111"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@android:drawable/presence_audio_away" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Burrows" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="0094 111 1111 111" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```